# Grab content of Iframe and place it in div class

Tags: jquery

I would like to grab content(text) from a div class of an Iframe and place it into another class outside of Iframe as text. This is what I tried but doesn't work:

```
var randomvar = $("#myiframe").contents().find(".divoftext");
$(".classwheretextneedtobeadded").delay( 5000 ).append( "randomvar");
```

I have been looking around but can't find something to work.

Thank you!

Comment: `.append( "randomvar");` <-- um you are appending a string, not the variable

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain?  Are there errors in the console? Did you inspect your code and make sure `$("#myiframe")` finds the iframe, that `$("#myiframe").contents().find(".divoftext");` gets the element?

Comment: hmm, I see. the iframe is not the same domain. Thank you for your response!

Comment: So it is not going to happen because of the same origin policy.

Comment: aaah I see, thank you very much